# Ionic5 split string

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Hello i want to split a string i get from a db row. The string is tags i use. I import them in db row as a text

e.g. the string is (#Hello, #hi, #hellothere )

and i want to split the tags like this to use each word as a button

```
<ion-row class="item-tags" *ngIf="item.tags?.length>0">
   <ion-col class="tag-wrapper">
      <span class="item-tag">
         <ion-note>{{item.tags}}</ion-note>
      </span>
   </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

.ts function

```
 export class UserPage implements OnInit {
     usersFlows:any =[];
       tagsArray: any;

    constructor(){}




usersFlowsSet() {//
this.offset = 0; 
this.userData.usersFlow().pipe(
  map((data:any) => {
    if (data.success) {
      this.usersFlows = data.userFlows;
      this.tagsArray = this.usersFlows.tags.replace(/#/g,'').split(', ')
    }
   })
 ).subscribe()
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Ciao, a simple `item.tags.split("#")` in string?

Comment: i put item.tags.split(",") but didnt work i am checking

Comment: no doesnt work !

Comment: {{item.tags.split(',')}} doesnt work

Comment: Ok this because slipt returns an array. You see something like [object,Object] or nothing?

Comment: doesnt return an array is a single object like this. 'Have, a, nice, day' and i want to use every single word as a button

Answer (score 0):

> and i want to split the tags like this to use each word as a button

Since you want to do this, why don't you split the tags inside your controller file.

`.split` function will not work in your html template.

```
this.tagsArray = this.item.tags.replace(/#/g,'').split(', ')
```

Then inside your template

```
<span class="item-tag" *ngFor="let tag of tagsArray">
   <ion-button>{{tag}}</ion-button>
</span>
```

Comment: thanks Chetan i updated to see the .ts function where do i pu the this.tagsArray?

Comment: You should put the line right after this.item is populated.. if you are getting this.item.tags data from a server call, then put that line after you receive the data..

Comment: i am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined i updated the code to see what i ve done. so my problem is i dont know to define the tags unless i put it in an ngFor

Comment: This error is self descriptive.. your `this.usersFlows.tags` is undefined, and that is why you see that error.. try console.log the value and see what is the value.. to avoid the error change your `if()` logic to `if(data.success && data.userFlows.tags)`.. check the edit in your question